# Calculating mean NDVI of two different locations

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, mean

I am trying to calculate mean NDVI of two location over a chart. I combined the two shapefiles successfully. Then I try to generate time series chart for both locations but only I obtained for one location. What i am trying to do both locations separate mean Ndvi visualization in chart?

Code:

```js
var extensiv = ee.FeatureCollection("users/Muhammad_Waqas/Location1");
var intensiv = ee.FeatureCollection("users/Muhammad_Waqas/Location2");

var classes = new ee.FeatureCollection([extensiv,intensiv]);
var classes_flatten = classes.flatten();
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterDate('2013-05-01', '2021-12-31').filterBounds(extensiv);

// Applies scaling factors.
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBands, null, true);
}

dataset = dataset.map(applyScaleFactors);
var table_bounds = function(image) {
  // Crop by table extension
  return image.clip(extensiv);
};
var NDVIClipped = dataset.map(table_bounds);

 var ndvi_func = function (i) {
      var ndvi = i.normalizedDifference (['SR_B5', 'SR_B4']).rename ('NDVI')
      return i.addBands(ndvi);
    }

    var image_ndvi = NDVIClipped.map(ndvi_func);

    //Calculating year wise NDVI
    var year = ee.List.sequence(2013,2021);
    var year_func = function(y){
      var range = ee.Filter.calendarRange (y, y, 'year');
      return image_ndvi.select('NDVI').filter(range).mean().set ('Year', y)
    };
    var yearwise_ndvi = ee.ImageCollection(year.map(year_func));
    print (yearwise_ndvi);
    Map.addLayer (yearwise_ndvi)


//Creating time-series chart:
var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion ({
  imageCollection: yearwise_ndvi,
  regions: extensiv,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 30,
  xProperty: 'Year'
}).setOptions ({title: "NDVI over time",
  hAxis: {title: 'Time of the year', format: 'year'}
});
print(chart)
```

Code Link.
[enter link description here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a9c9f1e95f40bebf3cd7486e4d84b7)

Result I want is like this for both shapefiles.

[image: Result I want]

Comment: The link you shared appears to be broken, could you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem using this code.

```
var provinces= table.merge(table2);
print(provinces);
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterDate('2021-05-01', '2021-12-31').filterBounds(provinces);
// Applies scaling factors.
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBands, null, true);
}
dataset = dataset.map(applyScaleFactors);
var table_bounds = function(image) {
  // Crop by table extension
  return image.clip(provinces);
};
var NDVIClipped = dataset.map(table_bounds);

 var ndvi_func = function (i) {
      var ndvi = i.normalizedDifference (['SR_B5', 'SR_B4']).rename ('NDVI')
      return i.addBands(ndvi).copyProperties(i,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
    }

    var image_ndvi = NDVIClipped.map(ndvi_func);

var NDVIchart = 
    ui.Chart.image
        .seriesByRegion({
          imageCollection: image_ndvi,
          // these are two geometries
          regions: provinces,
          reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
          scale: 300,
          //seriesProperty: 'label',
          xProperty: 'system:time_start'
        }).setSeriesNames(['Truman', 'Heffan'])
        .setOptions({
          title: 'Average NDVI Value by Date',
          hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
          VAxis: {
            title: 'NDVI (x1e4)',
            titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
          },
          lineWidth: 5,
          colors: ['f0af07','0f8755','76b349'],
        })
print(NDVIchart);
```

Comment: Please add details how it solved your problem and accept this answer as well.